# Statistics Problems, I don't understand what this means..

Tags: probability, statistics

P(A)=0.46 and P(B)=0.42

If P(B∣A)= 0.174

what is P(A∩B)?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you don't understand. Is the meaning of "P(A)=0.46" clear? etc..

Comment: I don't really understand what `P(A∩B)` means.

Comment: $P(A \cap B)$ is the probability that both the events $A$ and $B$ occur.

Comment: Questions asking about notation are perfectly valid; why are there so many close votes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may recall that
$$
P(B|A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}
$$ giving
$$
P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B|A)
$$Here you then have
$$
P(A\cap B)=0.46\times 0.174=0.08004.
$$